# How to replicate java encryption in c#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I have the public modulus and exponent for a key.  I am encoding a test piece of text and getting different results than the java code that I am trying to replicate.

The java code is here:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(rsaPublicSpec);
X509EncodedKeySpec encodedPublicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(“RSA”);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(encodedPublicKeySpec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(“RSA / ECB / PKCS1Padding”);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);    
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearTextString.getBytes());
BASE64Encoder b64 = new BASE64Encoder();
String base64EncodedStr = b64.encode(encryptedBytes);
```

What I have in C# right now using Bouncy Castle is:

```
BigInteger publicModulus = new BigInteger(1, Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyString));
BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1,Convert.FromBase64String("AQAB"));
RsaKeyParameters pubParameters = new RsaKeyParameters(false, publicModulus, publicExponent);
IAsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
eng.Init(true, pubParameters);
byte[] plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test data");
byte[] encdata = eng.ProcessBlock(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(encdata));
```

I'm a confused about why the java code gets the public key and then does the X509 version (and whether I need to do that in the C# implementation).
I'm also not sure if I need to compensate for endianness of c# vs. java.

Appreciate some help.

Comment: Sorry, added solution as a comment and should have answered the question.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

The confusing code didn't do anything. Also, Bouncy Castle wasn't actually needed once I got the modulus as a base64 string.  Here's what worked.

```
        var publicKey =
                       "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>base64modulusgoeshere</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
        var sbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
        var encdata = rsa.Encrypt(sbytes, false);
        enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encdata);
```

Comment: Also, I was assuming that I needed to get the same encrypted string out of java and .Net.  This isn't true because of random padding.  Even the same code generates different values that decrypt to the same result.